# How can I permanently remove the boot option "quiet splash"?

Tags: boot, grub2

When booting, I'd like to see the kernel output without having to edit the GRUB line on each boot. How can I do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Open a terminal and type the following:

```
sudo  gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Then look for a line like this in the opened file:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

It may have other options there as well, but just remove quiet splash and:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: the final step is to run `sudo update-grub` for any changes made to the grub.config file to be used, otherwise any changes made will not take effect until grub runs an update for another reason(like a new kernel install), otherwise your answer is good....also the question does not say which version of Ubuntu...if newer than 12.10(?maybe) gksudo will not be installed by default the correct way in that case is `sudo -i gedit.......`

Comment: Ah yes forgot the sudo update-grub! My bad! I didn't know that about gksudo, thanks for the info, and the -i sudo tip!

Comment: @TrailRider , the correct one (from now on) is `pkexec` and not `gksudo` (as you said correctly it has been removed due to some problems).

Comment: @NikTh I know that `pkexec` was *going* to replace `gksudo`, however I don't know if it did, last I knew it was not installed be default either, it may be now, but I know that `sudo -i` does work.....thank you for letting me know that `pkexec` is now available...

Comment: If you only have "quiet splash" in it, use this `sed -i 's/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=".*/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""/' /etc/default/grub
`

Answer (score 7):

Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and issue the following command

```
pkexec gedit /etc/default/grub
```

or

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

I assume here that gedit is installed on your system, if you prefer another editor use the appropriate name (e.g. leafpad, kate...etc).

Search, find and edit the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

proofread, save the document and then run in terminal

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Thank your too for your reply. When I tried to ran your first line, it didn't work: `~$ pkexec gedit /etc/default/grub 
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.

(gedit:6024): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: `

Comment: Although your comments to the other reply explains it, I'm too unfamiliar with this particular program so I just used `sudo`.

Comment: I added `sudo` again as an alternative. At 14.04 (that I have) `pkexec` works as it should. It seems that you have to provide some variables in order for `pkexec` to work properly. Try 
`pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY gedit`

Answer (score 4):

It's in `/etc/default/grub`. Make your changes there and update grub with `sudo update-grub`