# Two Monitors, login does not show up - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ati, login-screen, gdm

I'm trying to use Ubuntu 14.04 on my PC. I have two monitors and an ATI Radeon HD 4770 Video Card.

The thing is, after installing Ubuntu, and after reboot, the login screen does not show up, and the mouse does not move.

If I disconnect one monitor, everything works fine.

I think this is a Video Card issue, but i'm not sure about that.

Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: You have added "gdm" a tag. Why? Did you specifically install gdm after your first installation?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can to do to begin troubleshooting is disable the quiet splash boot options. See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/477828/366932

Once you do this, you'll see system messages fly past as the system boots. When things freeze, take a look at the last few lines displayed -- that will hopefully give you some hint about where things are going wrong.