# Cannot load Ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS

Tags: boot

Today I got up and tried to run my laptop
But do not get me after running out next?
Help How can I fix it. 
Because whatever he pushed me out black screen with a "_".
The only one I can think is that yesterday install League of legends.

Here are some pictures :

[image]
[image]

More information:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can edit the boot entries in the menu temporarily to display more information. Please try the following: Select the entry, press the key to edit this entry (it should be `e`), go to the kernel/linux line and remove `quiet splash`, then press `F10` to boot and post a new picture when it gets stuck again.

Comment: So far so good went into Ubuntu and how can I fix the problem does not go more? And system load normally :)

Once I entered I used this theme and then restarted : http://askubuntu.com/questions/477821/how-can-i-permanently-remove-the-boot-option-quiet-splash

Comment: *Edit:* okay looks like this comment is now obsolete, but could still be useful. That's unexpected, either my instructions were flawed or you didn't follow them completely. :( (Or the filesystem got corrupted and some grub modules damaged, but the *syntax error* messages indicate that it's a syntax error.) I guess I should have booted up a VM and made a screenshot in the first place, here we go: http://i.imgur.com/mmfmjaG.png

Comment: Once I entered I used this theme and then restarted : http://askubuntu.com/questions/477821/how-can-i-permanently-remove-the-boot-option-quiet-splash
But once it starts dropped it and then enter its normal (how can it not remove me out) :

http://imageshack.com/a/img633/1516/pGXkrT.jpg
http://imageshack.com/a/img910/1764/c66LSL.jpg
http://imageshack.com/a/img905/8326/CRqBgZ.jpg
http://imageshack.com/a/img910/5125/IZphcl.jpg

Comment: At least I'm getting a bit confused. I just included the images for you, could you please [edit] your question and let us know what the current status is or where it gets stuck?

Comment: Do what you say and then I went back in again, I use this tutorial to remove quiet splash (http://askubuntu.com/questions/477821/how-can-i-permanently-remove-the-boot-option-quiet- Splash) Now my PC run but before loading out here what I have given the pictures. (More information last four). And I would like to ask how I can do the operating system to boot as before without these things (tests)