# Very slow boot time ubuntu - A start job is running for Raise network interfaces

Tags: boot, networking

I am running ubuntu 16.04 and since few days it takes around 5 min to boot up. I looked related questions but I could not find how to troubleshoot my problem. When I run:

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

I get this utput:

```
5min 2.242s networking.service
     21.128s vboxdrv.service
      5.637s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      3.436s apt-daily.service
       592ms dev-sda1.device
       462ms lightdm.service
       442ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
       389ms libvirt-guests.service
```

So I guess networking.service is causing the problem. Can somebody help me to fix that? thank you

Comment: It might be worth disabling the boot splash/quiet setting to see the actual boot process. Most likely you'll see a timeout there regarding your networking-setup

Comment: @dufte I disabled the boot splash/quite setting (http://askubuntu.com/questions/477821/how-can-i-permanently-remove-the-boot-option-quiet-splash) and I see the follow: A start job is running for Raise network interfaces (5 min 2 s)...

Comment: This post seems to describe your problem: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2323253

Comment: @dufte see the answer and thanks for your help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe it is a workaround but I could reduce the boot up time following the answer at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2323253, i.e. by editing the file:

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/network-online.targets.wants/networking.service
```

And changing the following line at the end of the file:

```
TimeoutStartSec=5min
```

to:

```
TimeoutStartSec=30sec
```

I have then rebooted the system and it works fine.

If you dont want to reboot the system again, just reboot the daemon by:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: This is editing a package-provided file, so changes may be lost on upgrades. See my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by diegus is risky, because the file `/etc/systemd/system/network-online.targets.wants/networking.service` is a symlink to `/lib/systemd/system/networking.service`. This is owned by the `ifupdown` package and should not be modified: changes will be overwritten on the next upgrade of this package.

Better is to create a systemd [*override file*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659267/how-do-i-override-or-configure-systemd-services):

**`/etc/systemd/system/networking.service.d/override.conf`**

```
[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=30sec
```

The easiest way to create this file is through `systemctl` itself:

```
$ sudo systemctl edit networking.service
```

This will automatically also reload the file. Use `systemctl cat networking.service` to see if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above did not help me as my USB WLAN adapter stopped working after that.

But setting `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` under Ubuntu 18.04

```
#from
auto lo br0
iface lo inet loopback

# to 
auto lo
allow-hotplug br0
iface lo inet loopback
```

helped, as suggested here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1061852/650800

*The slow startup occurred after following [this tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/install-and-set-up-kvm-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) to install KVM.*