# how to fix " a start job is running for the raise network " in ubuntu server 16.0 LTS

Tags: networking, server

I have recently installed ubuntu server 16.04 LTS.a message is coming at the starting time " a start job is running for the raise network " & it takes too much time under offline network. but, when it comes to online makes no problem. how to make faster the startup process without this annoying message if I want to come offline ? and also there is a bridge connection named "virbr0" but not the simple ethernet network, why is this happening ?

need help .

Answer (score 19):

```
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp
```

to

```
allow-hotplug eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp
```

**For more information**
https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html

Comment: This fixed slow startup on Ubuntu 18.04 after installing KVM for Android Studio. My Android Emulators (VMs) + I still have internet connection so I guess nothing broke. Thanks alot!

Comment: Thanks, this solved our problem for laptops managed by puppet/debnet.  This commit is available for other folks in the same boat: https://github.com/rtib/tib-debnet/pull/18/commits/c1944642c8860085f87b92ed2494612f346fa6c5

Comment: This shoul be the accepted answer. Works like a charm

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer! Man, for the newbies ones, you should also add that the file you've changed is `/etc/network/interfaces`

Answer (score 18):

I seem to get the same issue and I also have a bridged network interface, probably from my VirtualBox setup, `enp0s31f6:avahi`.

My system is `ubuntu 16.04 LTS` server variant, installed on a laptop, so primary use is as a workstation.
As pr the comments this still applies for `ubuntu 20.04 LTS`.

The issue is there if the bridged interface is there, not if it's not present, say if VirtualBox has not been started inbetween reboots.

The reason is as in the other answer that this interface lacks init info.

My sollution was to reduce the timeout, and to do so without messing with the base installed networking.services systemd file. This will persist during updates in any package.

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/networking.service.d/
sudo bash -c 'echo -e "[Service]\nTimeoutStartSec=20sec" > /etc/systemd/system/networking.service.d/timeout.conf'
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (desktop) as well, thanks! I appreciate the additive nature of this solution.

Comment: This solved the long waiting time for me as well, however the root cause is not fixed which is that the bridged network interface suddenly stoped connecting to the internet. So the ubunut box within vb now has no internet connection.

Comment: I'm using a WLAN USB adapter and have the same issue. This fix makes the boot faster but then the wireless adapter does not work anymore. Resetting settings and plugging it out and in again helped. Damn, I was happy to find a quick solution.

Comment: Works also for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. My boot time was more than 5 min (crazy) and not is around 2.5 min. The only solution would be to make a clean install, rather than and upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps:

- Open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)
- Open `/etc/network/interfaces` file with `gedit` or `nano`:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
  ```
- Set below text for any interfaces in this file:

  ```
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback  
  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet dhcp  
  auto wlan0
  iface wlan0 inet dhcp
  ```
- Save the file and `reboot`

Comment: why 2 times the eth0 declaration??? before wlan0 and after wlan0?

Comment: I have corrected it. thanks a lot @PhilippeGachoud

Comment: Could you add a little explanation about what exactly this does?

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff I don't know if this is it's proper use, but I use it to force wireless connections on my network, because I have a weird wireless card. You can use it to define the network name, password and also manually configure DHCP

Comment: Folk who are more security conscious might prefer  `sudoedit` rather than `sudo $YOUR_EDITOR` so that the editor itself does not run as root. (If you don't like the system-wide default editor, you can `export SUDO_EDITOR=/path/to/your_favourite_editor` somewhere in your shell startup files; or create an shell function like `sudonano() { SUDO_EDITOR=$(command -v nano) sudoedit "$@" ; }`.)

Comment: For the record, this advice is directly contrary to that indicated elsewhere, which is that `auto` should be replaced with `allow-hotplug` instead. This makes a difference if your NIC is not connected at boot-up.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T)
2. Open `/etc/network/interfaces` file with gedit or nano:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
   ```
3. Set below text for any interfaces in this file:

   ```
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback
   ```
4. Remove any other entries.
5. Save the file and reboot

It solved for me.