# How to avoid 5 minute boot delay in 18.04: "A start job is running for Raise network interfaces"

Tags: wireless, ethernet, netplan

Problem: 5 minute delay on startup

Device: UP board (small x86 board), running 18.04, with a Panda PAU05 wireless USB adapter, connected via HDMI to a monitor

Network configuration: using netplan and systemd-networkd. NetworkManager is not installed.

When the Ethernet is connected, the device boots up quickly. I can unplug the Ethernet and rely on wifi. SSH works, etc.

When the Ethernet is not connected, there's a 5 minute delay. The console says `A start job is running for Raise network interfaces (Xmin Ys / 5min 2s)` and slowly counts up to 5min 2s. I can ping the device, but ssh is refused: `ssh: connect to host rodeobot.local port 22: Connection refused`. After 5 minutes the boot completes fine.

I tinkered with my netplan to make both ethernet and wifi interfaces optional, but this doesn't help. I also tried removing the ethernet interface, but that didn't help. Here's the `/etc/netplan/config.yaml` I'm running now:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      optional: true  # Don't wait for Ethernet
      dhcp4: true
  wifis:
    wlx9cefd5fcb328:
      optional: true  # Don't wait for Wifi
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "xxx":
          password: "yyy"
```

Edit: I see several similar questions, but I don't see an answer that uses netplan. Is this a bug / missing feature in netplan?

Edit: fixed indentation and commenting in config.yaml. (I copied and pasted, then edited the ssid and pw.)

Edit: here's the result of `sudo netplan --debug generate`:

```
** (generate:965): DEBUG: 18:35:38.361: Processing input file /etc/netplan/config.yaml..
** (generate:965): DEBUG: 18:35:38.362: starting new processing pass
** (generate:965): DEBUG: 18:35:38.362: wlx9cefd5fcb328: adding wifi AP 'Beckett'
** (generate:965): DEBUG: 18:35:38.362: wlx9cefd5fcb328: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:965): DEBUG: 18:35:38.362: Configuration is valid
** (generate:965): DEBUG: 18:35:38.362: enp1s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:965): DEBUG: 18:35:38.362: Configuration is valid
** (generate:965): DEBUG: 18:35:38.363: Generating output files..
** (generate:965): DEBUG: 18:35:38.363: NetworkManager: definition enp1s0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:965): DEBUG: 18:35:38.363: wlx9cefd5fcb328: Creating wpa_supplicant configuration file run/netplan/wpa-wlx9cefd5fcb328.conf
** (generate:965): DEBUG: 18:35:38.363: Creating wpa_supplicant service enablement link /run/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.wants/netplan-wpa@wlx9cefd5fcb328.service
** (generate:965): DEBUG: 18:35:38.364: NetworkManager: definition wlx9cefd5fcb328 is not for us (backend 1)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You've commented out "ethernets", and your indentation is incorrect. See my answer.

Comment: Check that your /usr/share directory is present owned by root, with 755 permissions.  I just saw a virtually identical error when a simlink for /usr/share was bad.

Comment: Thanks @heynnema. That was a copy/paste error. I verified that I'm running your correct version, and updated the question.

Comment: Thanks @ubfan1, I just checked, and /usr/share is owned by root, and has 755 permissions.

Comment: Does your wifi interface wlx9cefd5fcb328 have a route to the Internet, or is it local only?

Comment: The wifi interface does have a route to the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that enp1s0 wasn't managed by systemd-networkd, and therefore netplan had no effect. I discovered this by looking at the logs:

```
journalctl | grep enp1s0 | grep "managed by us"
```

I found a number of entries that looked like this:

```
systemd-networkd: enp1s0: Link is not managed by us
```

The fix was to remove the ifupdown package. For good measure (and to make sure I didn't forget!) I moved the /etc/network directory:

```
sudo apt remove ifupdown
sudo mv /etc/network /etc/network_old_ifupdown
sudo reboot now
```

While looking at the logs I also fixed a problem with resolv.conf -- I had a bad symlink. There's a good explanation here: [New alert keeps showing up: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058750/new-alert-keeps-showing-up-server-returned-error-nxdomain-mitigating-potential)

Thanks to folks that helped!

Comment: This is not the right fix for this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It fixed it for me.

Comment: That's because you were mixing Network-Manager and netplan commands. Your specific problem was with `/etc/network/interfaces`, and by renaming `/etc/network`, you just got that file out of the way. You should have just left `/etc/network/interfaces` as you found it originally, and not uninstalled portions of the OS to "fix" a different part of the system. You've handicapped your OS.

Comment: Yes, this device had a tortured history: a clean 16.04 desktop install, then I attempted to remove all vestiges of the GUI when it became a headless device. I should have wiped it and installed 16.04 server. In fact, there's still time to wipe it an install 18.04 server, which might fix a few other things. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: true
  wifis:
    wlx9cefd5fcb328:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "xxx":
          password: "yyy"
```

`sudo netplan generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply new configuration

`reboot` # verify proper operation

Comment: Still no luck. I added the results of `sudo netplan --debug generate` in case that helps.

Comment: @ClydeMcQueen Temporarily comment out all of the wifis stanza, leave just the ethernets, netplan generate/apply, and retest. If that doesn't work, temporarily remove dhcp4, set a static address and gateway, and retest. Report back.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. My solution was to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` by hand, replacing `auto enp1s0` with `allow-hotplug enp1s0`. I am surprised that `sudo netplan apply` didn't edit that file. I'm somewhat worried that my networking install is a bit broken. But now my boot times are quick w/ or w/o Ethernet plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

```
#from
auto lo br0
iface lo inet loopback

# to 
auto lo
allow-hotplug br0
iface lo inet loopback
```

[helped](https://askubuntu.com/a/1061852/650800). *The slow startup occurred under Ubuntu 18.04 after following [this tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/install-and-set-up-kvm-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) to install KVM.*