# Freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04 stuck at boot screen

Tags: boot, 20.04

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and for half a day everything was running ok until I connected it to my external monitor and everything is stuck loading in the boot screen. Not even forcing in to shut down works. What should I do?

Comment: Same issue here. Reinstalled many times before seeing your post and recognize it's due to 2nd monitor. Any help needed.

Comment: As a workaround, disable splash screen can help
https://askubuntu.com/questions/477821/how-can-i-permanently-remove-the-boot-option-quiet-splash

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar issue on Ubuntu 20.04 after the upgrade from 19.10. In my case, I noticed I could boot by disconnecting one of my two monitors.

So I have disabled the splash screen in the grub configuration and rebooted (sudo edit the file /etc/default/grub, remove the "splash" word on the line that starts with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, save the file and quit the editor, and then "sudo update-grub" to regenerate the grub init config). And now it works fine when booting with the two screens plugged in.